# REST API with different content types

Tags: api, rest, web-applications, content-type

I have a REST API endpoint to modify a resource i.e. PUT. The resource can have a file associated with it so I support two different content types: application/json and multipart/form-data. The first is for modifying the resource without associating a file and the second for when I want to associate a file with the resource.

What is the best way of representing this? Should I use the same URI for two different content-types e.g. update/:resourceId? Should I have two different endpoints e.g. update/:resourceId and updateWithResource/:resourceId? Or is this completely the wrong way to go and I should do something else?

Comment: I don't understand the first paragraph. "can have a file associated"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Content types are just different representations of the same ressource. So as long as they represent the same thing, they can, and they should, share the same URI.

URI should not affect content type, that's not RESTish. Negotiate the representation only with the content-type header.